# Is the Python non-daemon thread a non-detached thread? When is its resource freed?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, subprocess

Will the resources of non-daemon thread get released back to OS once the threads completes? ie If the main thread is not calling join() on these non-daemon threads, will the python GC call join on them and release the resources once held by the thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you spawn a thread that runs a function, and then that function completes before the end of the program, then yes, the thread will get garbage collected once it is (a) no longer running, and (b) no longer referenced by anything else.

Answer (score 1):

> "
>   A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this
>   flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads
>   are left. The initial value is inherited from the creating thread. The
>   flag can be set through the daemon property.
>   Note Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources
>   (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released
>   properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them
>   non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event.
>   " -- [Python Thread Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

Daemons are cleaned up by Python, Non-daemonic threads are not - you have to signal them to stop. This is useful in executing some complicated parallel code though :)
This does mean though you can have random dummy / useless threads sitting around for you to manually cleanup if you use non-daemonic threads.

tl;dr Non-daemonic threads never 'finish' you have to signal them to finish via your own mechanism or one of the SIGS e.g. SIGTERM.